# Jquery load function not working to get external page data for Codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery

I need to display some part of data in the website with load spinner, I am using codeigniter so my view file is like below.

when i click on the product link it loads this view file, My intention is if the user clicks on product link it should check and retrieve all the prices from the eCommerce sites. Basically its a price comparison site. Here when we click on the product, the prices are being fetched and only then the whole page is loading and the problem is its taking too much time, so what i want here is to load the whole page first and then fetch and display the prices of the product from different sites and while that's happening the user should see a spinner animation. please help me how to solve this. I want this to happen just like tripadvisor fetches prices of different hotels but at first loads the rest of the page.

Kindly help

```
<div id="results>
    <?php
    $url = $p->url;
        if(preg_match("/flipkart\.[com|in]/is",$url))
        {
            if(preg_match('/<span class="selling-price.*?data-eVar48="(.*?)">/',get_page($url),$flipmatches))
            { 
            $price=$flipmatches[1];
            echo  '<h4>'.'Rs.'.$price.'</h4>';
            }
        }
        elseif(preg_match("/amazon\.in/is",$url))
            {
            if(preg_match('/<span id="priceblock_ourprice" class="a-size-medium a-color-price"><span class="currencyINR">&nbsp;&nbsp;<\/span>(.*?)<\/span>/', get_page($url),$amazonmatches))
            {
            $amazonmatches[1] = strtolower($amazonmatches[1]);
            $price = (float) str_replace(array('rs.', ','),'',$amazonmatches[1]);
            //$price=$amazonmatches[1];
            echo '<h4>'.'Rs.'.$price.'</h4>';   
            }
            elseif(preg_match('/<span id="priceblock_saleprice" class="a-size-medium a-color-price"><span class="currencyINR">&nbsp;&nbsp;<\/span>(.*?)<\/span>/', get_page($url),$amazonmatches))
            {
            $amazonmatches[1] = strtolower($amazonmatches[1]);
            $price = (float) str_replace(array('rs.', ','),'',$amazonmatches[1]);
            //$price=$amazonmatches[1];
            echo '<h4>'.'Rs.'.$price.'</h4>';   
            }
        }

    ?>
</div>
```